# Need help for code to let user try again in Python

Tags: python

Basically, I am creating this game which consists of the user answering some multiple choice questions. I want it so when the user gets the answer wrong once, they try again and if they get the answer wrong twice, the correct answer shows up. But right now, if the user gets the answer wrong, it skips to the next question. How can I do this? Any help is appreciated. Here is my code:

```
score = 0
def correct():
  print("Congratulations! You got a point!")
  global score
  score = score + 1
  print("Points: ",score)
  
def incorrect():
  print("Wrong, try again!")
  print("Points: ",score)
  
  
def question(q,a):
  print(q)
  answer = input("Answer: ")
  if answer == a:
    correct()
  else:
    incorrect()

question("What is the capital city of England?\n a. London\n b. Paris\n c. York", 'a')
question("What is the capital city of France?\n a. Rome\n b. Paris\n c. Jersey", 'b')
question("What is the capital city of Germany?\n a. Accra\n b. Weimar\n c. Berlin", 'c')
question("What is the capital city of The Netherlands?\n a. Moscow\n b. Amsterdam\n c. Cape Town", 'b')
```

Comment: Can you add only the necessary code on here, instead of the link.

Comment: after `incorrect()` You call the question function again `question(q,a)`

Answer (score 1):

Use a `for` loop.  If a correct answer is given, `return` early from the function.

```
def question(q,a):
    print(q)
    for attempt in range(2):
        answer = input("Answer: ")
        if answer == a:
            correct()
            return
        else:
            incorrect()
    print("The answer is:", a)
```

Note: based on the code in the question, the call to `incorrect()` will always write "try again".  You might not want it to print "try again" after a second failed attempt, because the player does not get to try again in that case.  You could change this by passing in the attempt number as a parameter to the `incorrect` function and put a suitable `if` condition in that function to decide whether to print "try again" or not.

Comment: this is good too, but an alternate would be to make use of  `while True:` and then break at the end after `correct()`.  this leaves out ambiguity for needing a `range()` of some sort.

Comment: @FishingCode the user only gets two attempts - if there are two wrong answers, it moves onto the next question.

Comment: Ah, missed the bit about the correct answer shows up. I'll add that...

Comment: ah yup. that's right only 2 attempts.

Answer (score 1):

You could modify question function:

```
def question(q,a):
  print(q)
  answer = input("Answer: ")
  if answer == a:
    correct()
  else:
    print(q)
    answer = input("Answer: ")
    if answer == a:
      correct()
    else:
      incorrect()
```

Comment: this is only repeating the user input, and keeps checking again if the answer is incorrect, more of a hard-code.

Comment: true solution by @alaniwi is more elegant